# Pair iPhone with Ubuntu using bluez 5.17

Tags: iphone, ubuntu, bluez

I am using the graphical interface to find and pair the iPhone with my laptop. On the iPhone I can see the 6 digit number, but on the ubuntu bluez interface I can't.
When I observe the bluetooth traffic with hcidump I can see the following:
Directly after sending the request to confirm the numbers, my computer seems to receive a negative reply from the iPhone and thus quits the pairing process.

I compiled the bluez-tools on my computer to use "btmgmt pair " for the pairing which results in the exactly same error. Using bluez-simple-agent also does.

I would be glad if you could help me!

Comment: A friend observes the same problem. It first occured after he paired the devices successfully, unpairs them and then retries the pairing process. Pairing a different device now is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

what version of ubuntu are using for it?
I overcame this issue on 12.04 with 4.101

Comment: After reinstalling my virtual machine I could not reproduce this behavior anymore. My version ubuntu version is 13.10.